# Remove ^M from text file

Tags: awk, delimiter

I have text file which shows ^M character when opened using less command in mac terminal.
I tried using the below command to remove ^M character.

```
awk '{ gsub("\n", "\r"); print $0;}' input > output
cat input | tr ‘\n’ ‘\r’ > output
```

But none of them worked. Could someone help to fix this using some Linux commands.

Comment: cannot install in mac

Comment: The answers below tell you how to remove `^M`s as you requested, but they're wrong if you actually only want to remove the `^M` that appears at the end of a line for files with DOS line endings since they'll remove either the first `^M` or all `^M`s instead of just one that appears at the end of a line. To handle those correctly see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
 sed 's/^M//' filename > newfilename
```

If you wish to use `awk` then do:

```
awk '{sub(/^M/,"")}1' filename > newfilename
```

To enter `^M`, type `CTRL-V`, then `CTRL-M`. That is, hold down the `CTRL key` then press `V` and `M` in succession.

**Update**

As suggested by [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) in comments, it is easy to use `\r` then to get `^M`

Comment: use "\r" instead of "ctrl-v ctrl-m"

Answer (score 2):

```
col < input > output
```

Or:

```
vim "+set ff=unix" "+saveas output" "+q" input
```

Answer (score 1):

use the octal value from http://www.asciitable.com/

> echo "1'2^M34" | awk 'gsub(/\015/,":")'
> 1'2:34