# concatenate pairs of lines without ^M appearing

Tags: awk, sed

My file (temp.txt) looks like this:

```
-2011-10-07 11:30:01
00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:17
00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:32
00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:46
00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
```

I want to concatenate each pair of lines so it looks like this:

```
-2011-10-07 11:30:01 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:17 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:32 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:46 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
```

However every method I've tried (sed, awk, paste) inserts ^M between the pairs like this:

```
-2011-10-07 11:30:01^M 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:17^M 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:32^M 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:46^M 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
```

In vi the ^M appears in blue and can be removed manually but not by pattern matching. It comes up with "pattern not found" error. [sed and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024793/remove-m-from-text-file) haven't worked either. When opened in gedit or exported to a spreadsheet the carriage returns mean that it appears as in the first file. Since my file is much larger than the segment here, and I have 6 months of daily files to analyse, manual removal is not an option.  Please help!

Comment: Thank you to everyone!  The data is from an external source, and since I didn't see it in the original data when opened in vi I thought it must have been added during concatenation. I used `s/\r//g` in sed before concatenation and it worked perfectly.  Now to test on the full dataset...

Answer (score 1):

The `^M` form is called "caret notation", and represents a carriage return. Your files are using DOS end of line characters. Convert them to Unix format.

You can do this by run `dos2unix` on your input files, or piping them through `tr -d '\r'`.

In both `vi` and `sed`, you could have used `s/\r//g` to replace them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`. This works with UNIX and DOS format input so no need to use `dos2unix` on file.

```
sed 'N; s|[\r\n]\+| |' file
```

Output:

```
-2011-10-07 11:30:01 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:17 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:32 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
-2011-10-07 11:30:46 00 ///// ///// ///// 00000C00
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is not the tools you are using to process your input file, it's the tool that generated your input file.

```
tr -d '\r' < file | awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS)}1'
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:"\n")}1' file
```